# How to replace a single occurrence of a specific word in a text file

Tags: powershell, replace, file-get-contents

I have a configuration.txt file which my script uses to populate variables in my script.  The Tex file reads like:

```
Setting1= Yes
Setting2= Yes
Setting3= Yes
```

I then populate my variables as such (to pull just Yes or No):

```
$Setting1=(Get-Content -Path .\configuration.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match 'Setting1='})
$Setting1=($Setting1 -Split '=', 2)[1].trim()

$Setting2=(Get-Content -Path .\configuration.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match 'Setting2='})
$Setting2=($Setting2 -Split '=', 2)[1].trim()

$Setting3=(Get-Content -Path .\configuration.txt | Where-Object {$_ -match 'Setting3='})
$Setting3=($Setting3 -Split '=', 2)[1].trim()
```

Then I have some logic and if the user, via prompts in my script, change these settings, the script updates the text file with the following code:

```
((Get-Content -Path .\configuration.txt -Raw | Where-Object {$_ -match 'Setting1'}) -replace $Setting1, $UserSetting1) | Set-Content -Path .\configuration.txt
```

Where $UserSetting1 is the user's input (either 'yes' or 'no').

Now what this is doing is changing every 'yes' or 'no' in the configuration file instead of only changing the 'yes' or 'no' on the particular line I am trying to use the match function to pull out.

In other words if the user wants to change setting1 to 'no' and keep settings 2 & 3 as a 'yes'; the script is changing all the settings to Yes, instead of only setting1.

I am under the impression that I have to use -Raw in order to perform a -replace, but as stated above, it seems that the -match function doesn't work with the -Raw function...and if I don't use -raw, then my configuration file is re-written with only the single line that I matched.

Comment: The `-Raw` switch reads a file in as one string, otherwise each line is read and stored in an array. In the single string scenario, the entire file contents will be returned on a match; so when you replace “yes” it replaces it in all places. Not using `-Raw` is easier here to me.

Comment: Instead of separate `Get-Content` commands, I’d just do one and pipe it to `Foreach-Object` and match and replace against the pipeline object `$_`

Comment: there is at least one module on the PSGallery that handles INI files. your file sure looks like an INI file ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the [Replace Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-6#replacement-operator) to make an update.

```
$UserSetting1 = 'No'
(Get-Content -Path .\configuration.txt) -replace '(?<=Setting1=).*',$UserSetting1 |
    Set-Content
```

Since `-replace` uses a regex matching mechanism, you can construct the match to only return the data you want to replace. The replacement string can be a variable. See below for the regex explanation. It matches the remaining characters on a line after `Setting1=` and then replaces those characters with the value stored in `$UserSetting1`. Lines that have no match will be returned as is without replacement.

- `(?<=)` is the regex positive lookbehind assertion. It asserts that at a given position in the string that there is an exact match behind it.
- `Setting1=` literal match of the string `Setting1=`.
- `.*` as many characters as possible until the end of string (just before the newline character)<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

Using the `-Raw` switch reads the file contents as a single string. If you perform a regex match (`-match`) on a single string that has a match, `$true` is returned. The entire string is considered a match and defaults to capture group 0. `$matches[0]` contains that match. Therefore, if you use `-replace` to replace a substring within that match, it will replace *every* instance of that substring that meets the `-replace` matching criteria.

If the `-Raw` switch is not used, then the file contents are read in as an array of lines. `-replace` alone would still replace every instance of a match. However, you can now use `-match` and `Where-Object` to execute different code for certain matched lines.

Combining `-match` and `-replace` without `-Raw` could lead to only a subset of your read data. As you process each line of the file, `-match` will essentially filter out any lines that don't return `$true` *before* you process any replacements. This scenario is fine for returning the replacement, but can cause issues when you are trying to rewrite an entire file. You would need additional logic to track which array elements you have and have not modified and output them appropriately when you update your content.

---

<sup>[1] `.` *can* match newline characters if the regex mode is single-line. You can enable this mode in the `-replace` regex by beginning it with `(?s)`.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, it took me a second, but that works very well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to read the configuration file and store the name/value pairs in a Hashtable.

If the order in which the settings appear in the text file is not important, you could use the `ConvertFrom-StringData` cmdlet.
This will parse the settings names and values and returns it as Hashtable.

```
$config = Get-Content -Path .\configuration.txt -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

If the order **DOES** matter, create an ordered hash (needs PowerShell 3.0 or better):

```
$config  = [ordered]@{}
Get-Content -Path D:\configuration.txt | ForEach-Object {
    $name, $value = ($_ -split '=' , 2).Trim()
    $config[$name] = $value
}
```

If the user wants to change the value of `Setting1` to `no` for instance ($UserSetting1='no'), simply do:

```
$UserSetting1 = 'no'
$config.Setting1 = $UserSetting1

# Next save the updated settings back to the textfile
$newContent = foreach($name in $config.Keys) {
    '{0} = {1}' -f $name, $config.$name
}
$newContent | Set-Content -Path .\configuration.txt -Force
```